# Vocabulary building browser extension

Tags: web-browser, educational, language, translation

Are there any extensions for browsers where I can add words and build vocabulary to learn added words later?

I currently use Google Translate extension for Chrome, which is very useful. If I read an article and don't know the word, then I just double click on the word and I see translation, but I would like to learn them later also to not forget.

I imagine something like that, if I select the word and right click on it, then there will be option "add to vocabulary" for example. 
It would be even better if there will be possibility to take a test later with the added words.

Answer (score 1):

[Rememberry](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rememberry-translate-and/dipiagiiohfljcicegpgffpbnjmgjcnf/related?hl=en) seems quite good (for learning foreign languages). It allows you to save new words as flash cards that you can study later (and that in different modes, either they flash you the card and you need to remember the translation, or you listen to the word and then translate it, or they give you the foreign word and you need to translate it into your mother tongue, etc.).

If you are working on expanding just your English language vocabulary, [Cabulary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cabulary-vocabulary-flash/ejefgmegpcimohilbkiioplokdiangpd?hl=en) should work well. It enables you to add new words to the deck and review at anytime from the plugin.